# Finding the right word for a process

Tags: synonyms

How would one say that he did the same thing (e.g. making the same dish) but in different ways in a single word?

a more elaborated example would be, I used different technologies to achieve the same goal/result.

EDIT:

i'll add another example because I feel like you misunderstood me.
someone built a program (computer software) and implemented it in all sorts of different frameworks, he called the website that show this process "custom-elements-everywhere".

I built the same program using different frameworks (as a wrapper to ease the process of creating it) and implemented it in a single framework, therefor my website name should be "custom-element-".

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Comment: I actually did edited the question, and no one gave an answer since.

Comment: I really don't understand your second example. My understanding of a framework (dot Net for instance) is that it allows you to use any one of a number of languages to achieve the same result and that the output (object code?) is the same whichever language you used. I can just about get my head around the idea that someone might use different languages within the same framework to implement the same process model but I don't understand the bit about "different frameworks being implemented in a single framework". Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

> - *I* ***[`differently`](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/differently?s=t)*** *achieve the same goal/result.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "alternative" recipe/method/procedure?

However be aware of wording it in a way that doesn't sound like euphemism the way "alternative facts" does.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the person **consistently employed *creative* methods to achieve the goal.**

In this sense, `creative` is used to refer to the fact that the person was being imaginative in their choice of methods to employ.

Answer (score 0):

Use the words **methodologies** or **techniques** to accomplish the same end result.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/methodology

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/technique

Answer (score 0):

Professor Wong was able to synthesize ultrasucrose in an atmosphere of evaporated lithium.  His feat was soon **replicated** using copper, hydrogen, and a mild infusion of wild rosemary, the latter being found by students in Athens who started from a matrix of honey, as opposed to the usual thin film of invert sugar on a glass substrate.